# Remove free disk space

Tags: hard-drive, apfs

After reinstalling the system, a strange free space appeared on the system disk and because of this, the disk size decreased by 40GB. Apparently, we need to increase the size of the apfc container, but I get the error "the container could not be verified completely" nothing changes.

**UPD:**

I lost hope of fixing this problem, so I just reinstalled the system and now the full volume of my disk is available to me. Thanks for trying to help me guys :)

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] with the exact command you're using to try to increase the size of the container and the exact and full error message you're getting.

Comment: Does your disk really not have a name? The 15.4GB and 36.4GB volumes should have names.